# Jmeter Beanshell keeps adding backslash to parameter value

Tags: cookies, jmeter, beanshell

I have a simple scenario - let's say I need to set a cookie from user defined variable:

https://image.prntscr.com/image/v0J2SU5MQiejS9yY2aNuog.png

I'm using BeanShell pre-processor:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Cookie;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager;
CookieManager manager = ctx.getCurrentSampler().getProperty("HTTPSampler.cookie_manager").getObjectValue();
Cookie cookie = new Cookie(".test", vars.get("BEGIN"), sampler.getDomain(), sampler.getPath(), false, System.currentTimeMillis());
manager.add(cookie);
sampler.setCookieManager(manager);
```

Resulting cookie looks different:

```
Cookie Data: .test="{\"name\":\".prism\",\"token\":\"";
```

How do I remove backslash from it?

Comment: its a json file that has the `"` value escaped

Answer (score 0):

Issue was solved by downgrading from Jmeter 3.3 to Jmeter 3.0